# Scale Feynman Diagrams to Poster Size

Tags: scaling, beamerposter, feynmf

I am creating a poster using `beamerposter`, and I would like to include Feynman diagrams generated using `feynmp`. However, the native scaling of `feynmp` is indented for letter-size documents, and is far too small for a poster. Is there a way to scale the diagram to poster-size while keeping its features properly proportioned?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx. Can you provide a MWE? Did you try `scalebox` or `\adjustwidth` or `resizebox`?

Comment: `\setlength{\unitlength}{4\unitlength}` will scale the diagrams four times their original size.

Comment: `scalebox` is closest to what I need. However, it also blows up the font sizes as well on the labels, which were already enlarged from beamerposter. The `setlength` solution just stretches out the diagram, so it looks very thin and wiry. Perhaps I should just create the diagram as a standalone pdf, and then use it in the main document via `includegraphics`.

Comment: @xvtk In case you solved this the way you mentioned, can you post (and accept) that as an answer so this question isn't considered "unanswered" by the system anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the workaround I used. I created the Feynman diagram in its own `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\unitlength=0.5mm

\begin{fmffile}{feyn_fig}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,50)

...[feynmp stuff here]...

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

and I compiled it with `pdflatex` and `mpost`. The `standalone` package takes care of removing the extra bordering whitespace. I included the Feynman diagram in the main document (the poster) with `\includegraphics`, which properly scaled both the diagram's features and text.